# Simple jQuery plugin that excerpt text

Tags: javascript, jquery

First I work on all of my projects alone, and I feel like I need my code to be reviewed by others and deep dive into performance and best practice ... etc.

I created a simple jQuery plugin that excerpts text of an element depending on whether lines / characters count.

1. If option of type was set to chars the method of `_excerptTillChar` will be invoked and will excerpt the text of the element.
2. Else if the option of type was set to `lines`. the method of `_getTotalCharsInLines` will be invoked and get the width of character and expected height of the whole lines then get approximate length of text and that number actually is less than it should be, so I iterate over the text again increasing the length of text while the height is still as wanted.

Here is the source code

```
;(function($, window, document, undefined){
  'use strict';
  // define the plugin name and the default options
  const PLUGIN_NAME = 'ellipsis';
  const VERSION     = '0.1.5';


  /**
   * the default options of Ellipsis
   * @type {Object}
   */
  const DEFAULTS = {
    type: 'lines',
    count: 3
  };



  /**
   * the styles of span used to calculate height
   * of each line
   *
   * @type { Object }
   */
  const SPAN_CHAR_STYLE = {
    visibility: 'hidden',
    opacity: 1,
    display: 'block',
    position: 'absolute',
  }



  /**
   * different custom events shoud
   * @type { Object }
   */
  const EVENTS = {
    namespace:   '.ellispsis',
    initialize:  'initialize.ellipsis',
    initialized: 'initialized.ellipsis',
    update:      'update.ellipsis',
    updated:     'updated.ellipsis',
    excerpt:     'excerpt.ellipsis',
    excerpted:   'excerpted.ellipsis'
  };



  /**
   * Ellipsis class that excerpt the text of an attached element depending
   * on number of lines / characters
   * @param  {HTMLElement} element   attached element to excerpt it's text
   * @param  {Object}      options   list of custom options
   */
  class Ellipsis{
    constructor(element, options = {}) {
      this.element = $(element);
      this.options = Object.assign({}, Ellipsis.DEFAULTS, options);
      this.text = this.element.text();
      this._resizeTimeout = null;
      this._resizeHandler = this._updateOnResize.bind(this);

      this.init();
    }



    /*=========================================================================
     * PUBLIC
     *========================================================================*/

    /**
     * Public init() initialize the plugin and do logical stuff
     */
    init() {
      let result, charsNo;

      this.element.trigger(EVENTS.initialize);

      if(this.options.type === 'chars'){
        result = this._excerptTillChar(this.options.count);
      } else if(this.options.type === 'lines') {
        charsNo = this._getTotalCharsInLines(this.options.count);
        if(charsNo){
          this.element.trigger(EVENTS.excerpt);
          result = this._excerptTillChar(charsNo);
          this.element.trigger(EVENTS.excerpted);
        }
      }


      if(result instanceof Error){
        throw result;
      }


      if(this.options.type === 'lines') {
        $(window).on('resize', this._resizeHandler);
      }
      this.element.trigger(EVENTS.initialized);
    }



    /**
     * updating the ellipsed text.
     */
    update() {
      let number;

      this.element.trigger(EVENTS.update);

      if(this.options.type === 'lines') {
        number = this._getTotalCharsInLines(this.options.count)
      } else {
        number = this.options.count;
      }

      this.element.trigger(EVENTS.excerpt);
      this._excerptTillChar(number);
      this.element.trigger(EVENTS.excerpted);

      this.element.trigger(EVENTS.updated);
    }



    /**
     * reset ellipsis instance options
     * if any change is needed later.
     *
     * @param {Object} options text/type/count.
     */
    reset(options) {
      if(options.text) this.text = options.text;
      if(options.type) this.options.type = options.type;
      if(options.count) this.options.count = options.count;

      if(Object.keys(options).length > 0) {
        this.element.text(this.text);
        this.update();
      }
    }



    destroy() {
      $(window).off('resize', this._resizeHandler);
      this.element.text(this.text);
      this.element.off(EVENTS.namespace);
    }



    /*=========================================================================
     * private Methods
     *========================================================================*/
    /**
     * excerpt the text and leave a dedicated number of chars.
     *
     * @param { Number } number the total number of chars should be in element
     */
    _excerptTillChar(number) {

      if(number <= 0)
        return new Error('Number of chars to be shown is equal to or less than zero !!');

      if(this.options.type === 'lines' && number >= 3)
        number -= 3;

      if(number >= this.text.length)
        return null;

      return this.element.html(this.text.slice(0, number) + '...');

    }



    /**
     * get the number of characters in dedicated
     * number of lines.
     *
     * @param { Number }  linesNo  positive number that represent lines no.
     * @return { Number } the total number of chars that could be in the lines.
     */
    _getTotalCharsInLines(linesNo) {
      let count = 0;
      let $charSpan;
      let spanId;
      let height;
      let charWidth;

      if(linesNo <= 0) {
        return 0;
      }

      spanId = 'ellipsis_char_' + this._getIdNo()
      this.element.append(`<span id="${spanId}" class="jquery_ellipsis">W</span>`);

      $charSpan = $('#' + spanId);
      $charSpan.css(SPAN_CHAR_STYLE);
      charWidth = $charSpan.width();
      count = linesNo * this.element.width() / charWidth;
      height = linesNo * $charSpan.height();


      if(count >= this.text.length){
        $charSpan.remove();
        return null;
      }

      $charSpan.text(this.text.slice(0, count));
      $charSpan.css('max-width', this.element.width());

      while($charSpan.height() <= height &&
            this.text.length >= $charSpan.text().length + 1) {
          $charSpan.text(this.text.slice(0, $charSpan.text().length + 1));
      }

      count = $charSpan.text().length;

      $charSpan.remove();

      if(count >= this.text.length){
        return null;
      }

      if(count && typeof count === 'number') count --;
      return count;
    }



    /**
     * handler that used to call update method
     * with a debounce period.
     */
    _updateOnResize() {
      clearTimeout(this._resizeTimeout);

      this._resizeTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        this.update();
      }, 300);
    }



    /**
     * get unique id for each span
     * that used for calculation
     */
    _getIdNo() {
      return $('jquery_ellipsis').length;
    }


    /**========================================================================
     * GETTERS
     *========================================================================*/
    static get DEFAULTS () {
      return Object.freeze(DEFAULTS);
    }

  }


  /**
   * extend JQuery fn and initialize the plugin
   * @param  {Object}   options   custom setting of Plugin
   * @return {Object<Plugin>}   instance of jquery Plugin
   */
  $.fn[PLUGIN_NAME] = function ( options ) {
    var args = arguments;

    if (options === undefined || typeof options === 'object') {
      return this.each(function () {
        if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + PLUGIN_NAME)) {
          $.data(this, 'plugin_' + PLUGIN_NAME, new Ellipsis( this, options ));
        }
      });
    } else if (typeof options === 'string' && options[0] !== '_' && options !== 'init') {
      var returns;

      this.each(function () {
        var instance = $.data(this, 'plugin_' + PLUGIN_NAME);

        if (instance instanceof Ellipsis && typeof instance[options] === 'function') {
          returns = instance[options].apply( instance, Array.prototype.slice.call( args, 1 ) );
        }

        if (options === 'destroy') {
          $.data(this, 'plugin_' + PLUGIN_NAME, null);
        }
      });

      return returns !== undefined ? returns : this;
    }
  };



  // init the plugin on data attribute
  $(document).ready(function() {
    let elementsToEllipsis = $('[data-toggle="ellipsis"]');

    elementsToEllipsis.each((i, element) => {
      let $element = $(element);
      let options = {};

      if( $element.data('type') !== undefined )
        options.type =  $element.data('type');

      if( $element.data('count') !== undefined )
        options.count = $element.data('count');

      $element.ellipsis(options);
    });
  });

  /* strip-code */
  window.__ellipsis__ = Ellipsis;
  /* end-strip-code */

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

**Note** get characters count in lines mode can be counted using binary search, and I tried it already.  But in most cases I found the performance a little bit better when I use the integrated method.

Also I have a problem with resize, don't know what to do. Should I disable this option and let the user decide to update on resize or not using public `update()` method?

There is another issue, when I inspected the timeline on chrome when apply the plugin to such as 40 elements I found FPS load issue that takes over 2500 ms and I don't know why.

For more details here is the repo of the plugin
https://github.com/pencilpix/ellipsis

Comment: Are you looking for code review or solutions to stated issues?

Comment: actually, I'm looking for review not a solution, I know here is just for code review only